# Why are the NCAA volleyball seasons for men and women different?

Tags: collegiate, volleyball, schedule

In the NCAA, the women's volleyball season runs from late August/early September until December. The men's volleyball season runs from January to early May. Why the difference?

Is it due to the women having a beach season in the spring? Why don't men have beach volleyball?